# Mayavi mlab_source.set opacity doesn`t work

Tags: opacity, mayavi, mayavi.mlab

I have two parts of code:
This part works perfictly:

```
        @on_trait_change('scale_range, scene.activated')
        def update_range(self):
            label_unique = labels[0]
            self.cur_scale = self.scale_range
            cur_scallars_len_list = [np.array(x) for x in scallars_len_list[0]]
            for ii in range(len(label_unique)):
                points_dict[label_unique[ii]].mlab_source.set(
                    scalars=cur_scallars_len_list [ii]*self.cur_scale)
```

And this doesnt work and i get no errors:

```
@on_trait_change('opacity_range, scene.activated')
 def update_opacity(self):
    label_unique = labels[0]
    self.cur_opacity = self.opacity_range
    for ii in range(len(label_unique)):
        points_dict[label_unique[ii]].mlab_source.set(opacity=self.cur_opacity/100).
```

Comment: Please, provide a minimal, complete and verifiable example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: the code seems to be very big - stackoverflow restricts to add it. Can i send you an email?

Comment: You could publish the code and link it here. Perhaps I could help you getting a mvce, but I cannot guarantee it.

Comment: Here is the link https://docs.google.com/document/d/1Xo6KCZohVjoAhVnkigTRvBO4bxhefm7xAvlCq_tHYc4/edit